# Slow startup in Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

When making a change in a Play Framework 2.2.3 application, AFTER compilation the first page load takes 34 seconds (subsequent loads are fast).
It might be worth noting the computer is not connected to the internet.
What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What plugins are you loading? Are you trying to connect to a database?

Comment: It happens with no plugins or database.

Comment: Check your `main.html` if there is too much of scripting involved then it might take some time. Also, check scala based processing in page.

Comment: Happens even if Application.index() just returns ok().